# When I edit a RAW photo in MacOS Photos, why does it go grey?

Tags: macos, big-sur, photos

I have imported some photos from my Canon 7D into the Photos app on MacOS 11.4.
They are shot in RAW mode.

When I import them into Photos I can see them fine and edit them.
As soon as I've finished editing them, they appear as solid grey (gray) squares:

[image: Photos gray squares instead of RAW thumbnail]

If I revert them to original, or continue editing them, I can see them fine, but if I make any changes and keep them, the grey boxes are back.

Comment: Complete guess - editing the RAW somehow breaks [or breaks the connection to] the embedded jpg, which is likely what is being used for the thumbnail.

Comment: It's just appeared.. Must have been processing the thumbnail in the background or something... Should I delete or add as an answer?

Comment: Might be useful for future searchers. I just tested from a Nikon RAW & the thumb recalculated, as far as I can tell, immediately. [I don't usually do my "proper" photos in 'Photos'.]